# jquery uncheck checkbox with a link

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, hyperlink

please advice, I want to create tags. i have an input field in a div and multiple checkbox in another div. i want to add tags clicking checkbox. tags got a close button which remove that tag also uncheck the particular check box.

for example i have automobile, fashion, healthcare, education etc checkbox. typing in input box add tag and check box is checked by pressing enter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $list = $("#itemList");

$(".chkbox").change(function() {
    var a = this.value;
    if (this.checked) {
        $list.append('<li><a href="#">' + a + '</a></li>');
    }
    else {
        $("#itemList li:contains('"+a+"')").remove();
    }
})
$('div a').live('click', function(ev){
    alert("hi");
});


<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="101">  This is 101
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="102">  This is 102
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="103">  This is 103
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="104">  This is 104
</div>
<div id="items">
    <ul id="itemList">
    </ul>
</div>
```

plesae help or advice.

Comment: What's the problem?  Your code works as far as I can tell: http://jsfiddle.net/yU8uL/1/

Answer (score 2):

Morning

try this

```
var $list = $("#itemList");

$(".chkbox").change(function() {
    var a = this.value;
    if (this.checked) {
        $list.append('<li><a href="#">' + a + '</a><button class="closebutton" value="'+a+'">X</button></li>');
    }
    else {
        $("#itemList li:contains('"+a+"')").remove();
    }
})
$(document).on('click','div a',function(ev){
   alert($(this).text());
});
$(document).on('click','.closebutton',function(){
   var b = this.value;
   $("#itemList li:contains('"+b+"')").remove();
    $(".chkbox[value="+b+"]").removeAttr('checked');
});
```

This will create a close button which can also be clicked..

http://jsfiddle.net/jDBsw/3/

Answer (score 1):

The problem may with your .change. try

```
$(document).on('click','.chkbox', function() {
    var a = $(this).val();
    // same code as above
});
```

also .live is deprecated in the latest versions of JQuery. Do not use that.

Comment: first parameter must be: _[One or more space-separated event types](http://api.jquery.com/on/)_ not comma-separated